# TypeScript: Return correct type for object property by key

Tags: typescript

I have a const object with known keys. Each item may or may not have a specific property.
I want a function to, given the key, return the value along with it's appropriate type.

I'm using TypeScript 4.6.2.

Of course I can just type in `data.key?.property` but I need to do this programatically.

Here's a contrived example to show what I'm after:

```
const data = {
 alice: {loves: 3},
 bob: {loves: 'hippos'},
 charlie: {hates: 'toast'},
 denise: {loves: (a:number) => `hello`}
} as const;


function personLoves(name:keyof typeof data) {
    const item = data[name]
    const loves = 'loves' in item ? item.loves : undefined;
    // ^ this line is clearly not right!
    return loves;
}

const aliceLoves = personLoves('alice');
// I want `aliceLoves` to be type number. 

const bobLoves = personLoves('bob');
// I want `bobLoves` to be type string or 'hippo'

const charlieLoves = personLoves('charlie');
// I want `charlieLoves` to be type undefined

const deniseLoves = personLoves('denise');
// I want `deniseLoves` to be type (a:number) => string
```

TypeScript playground here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvAUDBAbAS2AFMAuTPEAN2InIGYBfAGhwCMQ3yNKa6YA5AAsCAB1EgIAljmBCEAJ0JlM8qLXICoIBNGmt4xMAQgqe1DTAAUCUmACuAWzbEFASjQA+GAAMhxPEofRixGXAgYUEgoAG4seIAzezBgKAJwGFFXCHAAGQsIKzAERzIAa2IATxAEmChKrJr4JAQPbBgOyPBoGAJ1RzRm5ABtYtKAXRxOqJ7eWkGBOalesF7+mAB+NeJHADolmHJkuGIEgjBiODjOmAViKHsFVaW4kKwZ2HwiYny+QayFDkwL9aFYBF8SAI3HEAPQwmAASRgAHcEGBYFARBFtDAXHUGsQYA5nK5djB4h9cZwQRF0ACgTSwRw2FDYfCkaj0XUsXUQLjCfUsjBoApzgBzGAgBSCETiEACCndWByRTKGn-bJ5ApglVKAjEVlYOGIlFojE8nF4wWE46nc6XRXRQzGUzquma4HagQnF0G6FG9mmrmYky8-n4oU2OxOFzuLzCqCisBioA

Comment: using `return item.loves as (typeof data[T])['loves']` seems to actually return the right result, BUT also gives an error `Type '"loves"' cannot be used to index type '{ alice: { loves: number; }; bob: { loves: string; }; charlie: { hates: string; }; denise: { loves: (a: number) => string; }` :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation I'd recommend using a [generic signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#generic-functions) on `personLoves` to capture the idea that `name` is a *specific* key of `data`. That will allow TypeScript to track the correct associated return type based on the value you pass when you invoke the function.

In combination with that, I would use an [overload signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to capture the two situations you have: when the data for the person contains a `loves` key (in which case we infer the return type from the type of that key's value), and when it does not (in which case the return type is always `undefined`).

```
// A helper type that we will need to figure out which keys have values with a 'loves' property
type KeysExtending<O, T> = {
    [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends T ? K : never;
}[keyof O];

// Then, the keys of `data` which DO have a 'loves' key are:
type KeysWithLoves = KeysExtending<typeof data, {loves: unknown}> // resolves to: "alice" | "bob" | "denise"

// Then, write one overload case for keys in the above type, and another for everything else.
// Since overloads always try to match to the earliest listed overload, this will first capture the properties that DO have a 'loves' key, and infers the correct return type from that.
// Anything not caught by the first overload must be a name without a 'loves' key in its data, so we give it return type 'undefined'.

function personLoves<T extends KeysWithLoves>(name: T): (typeof data)[T]["loves"];
function personLoves(name: keyof typeof data): undefined;
function personLoves(name: keyof typeof data) {
    const item = data[name]
    const loves = 'loves' in item ? item.loves : undefined;
    return loves;
}
```

This seems to get the result you desire:

```
const aliceLoves = personLoves('alice');
// Is the literal number type: 3. 

const bobLoves = personLoves('bob');
// Is the literal string type: 'hippo'

const charlieLoves = personLoves('charlie');
// Is the type: undefined

const deniseLoves = personLoves('denise');
// Is the type: (a:number) => string
```

---

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-bFqIr-Cr8iUKjHwGbrdOifVmvWCDnjvVJjMq8HxsEV9MdYb+4nR9s9mcrg83jgsEU7zAEAA)

Comment: amazing - thank you so much, that works. Great explanations too :+1: